# Kindle Paperwhite Custom Fonts

Tags: kindle

I am getting  really bored with the old kindle fonts, I'd really like to add some new ones. Is it possible? (I have a 6th generation Kindle Paperwhite)

Comment: you need to jaillbreak

Answer (score 3):

I understand it is possible to add new fonts without jailbreaking as follows:

1. Remove DRM from Kindle files and make them convertible
2. Convert Kindle eBooks to AZW3 file with Calibre and embed the font in the Kindle file
3. Transfer the converted files to Kindle

There's additional details at this [article](http://www.epubor.com/how-to-install-custom-fonts-in-kindle-without-jailbreak.html).  The article states that the method works with the current Kindle eReaders and the older ones that support KF8 format eBooks.  I believe this includes your [6th generation Kindle (aka Paperwhite 2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle#Sixth_generation)

I have not tried this method myself, so "your mileage may vary."

Comment: We like complete answers here, with any links provided pointing to backup material, so that once the link-rot sets in the answers is still useful. Please expand your answer to include the relevant information.

Comment: @anthon Answer expanded.